# Method to find the number closest to the middle range in between from a given integer array

Tags: java, methods

This is what I acomplished so far. Can anyone help me?

Suppose `min` and `max` are already known:

```
public static int closestValue(int[] x, int max, int min){
    int mid = (max - min) / 2;
    int y[] = new int[x.length];
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
       // I do not know what to put here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please outline an example input and its expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the the closest number you can compare difference between each number with middle number and keep smaller.

```
public static int closestValue(int [] x , int max, int min) {
    int mid  = (max - min)/2;
    int m = x[0];
    int dif = 0, currentDif = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        dif = mid - x[i];
        currentDif = mid - m;
        if (dif * dif < currentDif *currentDif)
            m = x[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Using `Math.abs` may be better than squaring - it will avoid overflow for larger numbers.